# Quartz Spring Test JUnit

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

Como recurar um Job que esta operando em Cluster no Spring?

- Spring 4.3
- Quartz 2.2.3

Exemplo de declaração do Job

```
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class SysEncryptEmailSendSystemJob implements Job{
..
   @Override
   public void execute(final JobExecutionContext context) throws 
       JobExecutionException {
   }
}
```

Minha factory

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = SysConfig.SCHEDULER_FACTORY)
private SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory;
```

Sei que poderia anotar como @Component mas assim perde as funcionalidades do quartz, o objetivo de fazer a IOC é para fazer os testes com o JUnit!

Alguma forma de fazer isso? que alguém já fez?